# Getting latest data in a table from comma separated value joining with original table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created script to get the comma separated value, that value(cloumn1) joined with another table(column2), (column1) having n number of duplicate I want to get the latest top 1 from column1 and join with column2. script ->

```
SELECT A.EmailHistoryid,
    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String,
    A.MailTo
INTO #tmp
FROM (
    SELECT EmailHistoryid,
        CAST('<M>' + REPLACE([requestinstanceids], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String,
        MailTo
    FROM [emailhistoryDT] NOLOCK
    ) AS A
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/M') AS Split(a)
ORDER BY a.EmailHistoryid DESC;
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP(1) FROM #tmp ORDER BY EmailHistoryid DESC`?

Comment: top 1 need to join with original table, once we got the comma separated value, consider  (strin having multiple number of time that values we have to take the top 1)  string = requestdt.requestinstanceid